# Rails 3 Limiting Access so user can update only their data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller

This seems like something that should be fairly simple since it would be needed a lot.  I check to see if a user is logged in fine but once a user is logged in they could potentially alter other peoples accounts.  For example:  say user with ID 1 was logged in and they put /users/2/edit as the url.  This would show them user 2s data and allow them to modify it.  Of course I can alter the edit action in the controller to use something like this...

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  end
```

where current_user is set in the controller so the user is always that person who is logged in.  This is fine if you only have a couple controllers with a couple actions but could be a pain if you have many.  It seems like there should be a way to limit this globally so the user can only update their own data no matter what action or controller they use.

Is there a way to restrict the user to their own data for all actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your question is really about how to do *authorization*. Also, I suspect you might be conflating the "belongs_to" model association name with authorization. The "belongs_to" association name describes how one model relates to another, but it does not imply anything about how an application controls access to any model.

Hishalv is correct that using a controller filter is the right way to manage authorization. It's the correct MVC way. Give the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) a good read so you understand that.

Then, you can consider using an authorization gem like CanCan, or rolling your own per Hishalv's suggestion. CanCan works well in tandem with an *authentication* gem like Devise. If you do roll your own, it's a simple thing to put a helper method in ApplicationController and write it in such a way that it works regardless of the model.

Comment: thanks for the information.  I was merely mentioning the belongs_to as a way to know which models should be checked against for access permissions since the relationships are specified there.  Users -> posts etc.  I was looking for something that took advantage of these relationships to control access to data.  Thanks for pointing me in the direction of CanCan.  This is what I was looking for.  A way to specify all data access in one location without having to modify each action.    And of course the railscast showed the implementation perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

In your application_controller.rb you can try this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :validate_user

  private

  def validate_user() #might need to pass id and current_user
    if current_user.id == params[:id]
      # continue to current_user url
    else
        flash[:error] = "Please access one of your own pages"
        redirect_to(:back)
    end
  end
end
```

by putting the stuff in the application controller it should be available in all the controllers, however if you do not need to confirm that this is the current user (say maybe home page) then you may need to use a skip_before_filter in any specific controller(for a specific action) that needs it, like this in the pages controller for example

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :validate_user, :only => [:home, :about]
end
```

For more info checkout this [link to rails guides on filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters). There could be more efficient ways of achieving this as well.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I think I understand what you are doing.  This takes care of validating one parameter.  Basically you suggest doing one of these for each parameter you need to validate.  So if the user was editing a post there would be a post validater that would be needed as well.  So if you have 10 different models that could be updated you would need 10 validaters?  I am voting up because this is a better approach than doing each action in the controller but I will leave open to see if somebody is aware of a way to cover all.

Comment: OK either I am not understanding something or not being clear.  For example if post/3/edit belonged to user 1 and user 2 was logged on and typed post/3/edit you would need a post validator correct since the user_id is not in the params, just the post id.  You would have to validate that the post had a user_id matching the logged in user.  I was just wondering if somebody was aware of something that would validate all models that have a belongs_to user   against that user id globally.  Does that make sense or am I missing something in your solution that would catch this?

Comment: @Xaxum, ah, yes, that's correct, ignore my previous comment. i think its possible, but not sure how to go about implementing it.

Comment: I have the same problem, and didnt find the solution. Did anyone found the solution?

Comment: The condition should be - current_user.id == params[:id].to_i :)

Answer (score 1):

I have always found it a bit strange that end users were exposed to Rails "internals" such as `/users/2/edit` when all they wanted to do was update their own account.

So I prefer the method of calling it

```
resource :account
```

instead of

```
resources :users
```

Then you have paths like `/account`, `/account/edit` and so on, and need only handle data for the logged in user.

Comment: could you expand a little further?  I don't understand what using :user instead of :users would get you?

Comment: Thanks for explaining further.  I sort of do a hybrid of this where I create an account to consolidate different "account" data from multiple models but I still use the models controllers for updating and such hence my need for access restriction which Cancan does wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cancan then

```
def validate_user
 unless current_user.id == params[:id].to_i
  raise CanCan::AccessDenied
 end
end
```

And in application_controller write

```
   rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = "Access denied."
    redirect_to access_denied_path
  end
```