# Rails - Securely updating user information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

In many books and tutorials, I see people implementing the `update` method in users controller as either find the user data by params[:id] or session[:id]. However, I feel it possible to simply modify the session or the address bar to hack into someone else's account and modify his/her information. So how to I make sure the user can only update his/her own information instead of changing others.

Comment: [here you can find some answers for your question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340310/rails-3-limiting-access-so-user-can-update-only-their-data

Comment: Hacking the sessions is not simple at all.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is application specific. You'll need to first "find" the record - where the details of how to find that record depends on the application.

Yes, as you indicate, you should not just blindly instantiate the record and update it. Your business logic needs to intelligently find the pertinent record, before you expose it to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the User model the same as any other model and add your authentication to it and require the user to be logged in (e.g. current_user for some auth methods) within the uddate method.

```
if current_user
  update_stuff and redirect
else
  :notice => 'Not authd' and redirect
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I once had this problem when working on applications that required some things to be private. What I did was use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) along with great rails practices. I used Devise for authentication, cancan for authorization.

In some case you can pass the user id through your form using a hidden_field. I recommend passing the user_id in your controller create action and also when using devise you have access to the current_user method which would only create the model based on the current users session and id.

Secure the users information using cancan. For example if I could only show a users photos like so without user2 seeing the photos.

```
@photos = current_user.photos #only grabs current users photos
```

With cancan I could stop the user from manually entering a url like users/2/edit by doing somthing like this

**Ability.rb**

```
can :manage, Photo, :user_id => user.id
```

**controller.rb**

```
load_and_authorize_resource :photo

def index
  authorize! :index, @photo
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have actually done quite a bit of application building/research around this topic so I will try to give a detailed answer.

In the same kind of way you can divide sections of an application or website between non-users, signed-in users and admin accounts, you can implement checks to ensure that, for example, only the correct user can change their account password. Here is a test you might use for such a method:

```
describe "as wrong user" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
  before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

  describe "submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action" do
    before { get edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
    specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user')) }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
  end

  describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action" do
    before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
  end
 end
end
```

If you are new to testing (or unsure what this specifically does) I will explain:

In the code a factory can take an option (this particular line below)

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com")
```

This basically creates a user with a different email address from the default. Then all that is happening is the tests specify that the wrong user should not have access to the original user’s edit or update actions.

The next step would be to add a before filter to check the status of the current user. This might go in your `users_controller.rb` file.

```
before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
```

Then secondly (still in the users_controller.tb file) create a private method to check the current user has permission to modify the data otherwise redirect them back to the root url (if you were fancy you could use a [:notice] saying "you do not have access to this part of the applications" or something similar)

```
private
def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
end
```

The correct_user filter uses the `current_user?` boolean method which you define in the Sessions helper as follows:

```
def current_user
remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
@current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
end

def current_user?(user)
user == current_user
end
```

That isn't exactly the entire dogma for security when it comes to who can access what but I hope it provides you with the missing details mentioned in your question.